# Automatically delete local photos that have been backed up by Google+

Tags: backup, photos, google-plus

I use Google+ to automatically back up any photos taken with my phone. Unfortunately my phone has only 8GB storage. Is there a way to automatically delete the local copies of photos that have already been backed up by Google+ in order to save storage space?

Answer (score 1):

There is an app called "flickr uploader", since flickr offer 1TB free it's pretty convenient. This app allows you to auto backup  all your pictures to flickr and it has an option to delay the backup so you can delete blurry photos, for example, and of course, the option to delete the photo from the phone 24 hours after successfully uploaded.
I have been using it for a long while, totally worth it.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts – and thanks for taking the time to answer! But how does your approach help the OP with *Google+*? I don't see any indication of "switching to some other cloud service" being a valid option. So does that app support G+ as well?

Answer (score 0):

I have recently started trying to teach myself how to (properly) use [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) so thought this could be a nice little project to try.

Harder than I thought. I couldn't manage to do exactly what you want and it is a pretty crude method but I will continue anyway. I thought if I put it out there, someone with more experience with Tasker may be able to improve it.

So I started by creating the task "Delete last photo". Fortunately, doing this with Tasker is very easy as it has a build in variable `Last photo`.

Now the hard bit I found was choosing a trigger. Ideally it would be when you get confirmation of upload (Tasker does support HTTP responses but that stuff is way over my head, if it is even relevant) or when a photo is taken (which I couldn't find as an event within Tasker). So the way I settled on, and here comes the messy bit, was to have it run everytime the screen is turned on. I know this is a very poor trigger (e.g. If you have no network connection it will delete the photo without uploading it) but I could see no better options within Tasker.

I know this is far from the answer you will have been wanting but as there have been no other (proper) answers I thought I would get this in there, may give you or someone else a better idea.

Comment: I like the approach and will look into it. I, for a while now, wanted to teach myself to use tasker anyhow ;)

Comment: I don't use G+ autobackup feature so was new territory for me too. I did notice that G+ notifies you when pics have been uploaded too. Tasker also supports notifications as triggers so could be another avenue to explore.

Answer (score 0):

I am using an app called FolderSync ([paid version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.full)) to pack up my photos to cloud. 
You can set automatic delete of the local files, after transferring them. But with this you can't use Google+ 's automatic upload.