# How can I automatically delete the oldest Photos which are uploaded to the Cloud (Google+, Dropbox, …)?

Tags: sync, photos, google-plus, dropbox, cloud

When I was shooting photos mostly on my offline point and shoot camera, there was one obvious way to manage the pictures: copy them to desktop via USB, then delete from camera. This was typically automated using picasa out similar.

Then came the smartphones. You can still use the same technique, but Google+ and dropbox offer instant upload for backup purposes. So everything I shoot is copied to the cloud, but I still keep it in my phone. I can delete, but that's not automated at all. And I have to be sure not to delete stuff that wasn't yet uploaded.

Am I missing something here? Is there an obvious solution to this problem? Or is everyone fine with using USB like with regular cameras?

Comment: Solution to what problem?

Comment: @AlE. Problem: uploading my photos to a cloud storage service and removing the original. In an automatic and safe way.

Comment: Although there is no accepted answer, may be worth a read [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/67438/automatically-delete-local-photos-that-have-been-backed-up-by-google/75493#75493)

Answer (score 1):

Dropbox's new Carousel app has an option to "Free up phone space".  This will delete photos from your phone that have been uploaded to Dropbox.

It's not automatic, and perhaps not exactly what you want, but if the real problem is running out of space on your phone it will probably help.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I just delete photos from my device every month, and with Google+ photos its easy to see which have been uploaded and which haven't.

On the main "Photos" menu, above your photos there is a status for Auto-backup.

Also, from the "On Device" menu item, you can specify which folders get backed up.

Comment: _"with Google+ photos its easy to see which have been uploaded and which haven't."_ Could you add more detail please. When I go to "Photos > On device > Camera" I don't see any kind of indicator of which photos are backed up and which aren't. Should I be looking somewhere else?

Comment: You can see the status of the backup on the main "Photos" menu. If there are some pending then it is not finished.